# External Identity provider for WSO2 Identity server

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

It is possible to authenticate users with Facebook account, google account, twitter etc... through Oauth? (In the case of a web application try to access to a protected ressource)

I understood that WSO2 Identity Server can act as an authorization server and provides its own access token but it is possible to authenticate user if facebook or google provide access token after user authorize retrieving its info?

Comment: Hi CGI, did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Oauth is supported in identity server, but I doubt if it is necessary to have two of this authentication server together :) ?

Comment: Maybe it is not necessary to have two authentication server, so how can I authenticate users with Identity Server but with Facebook credentials or Google etc... ?